# File which include paths to different files

Tags: python, file, path

I want to make a file which include paths, but my problem is that a part of path is not the same e.g. it also includes different daytime which is an element of the path and I don't know how to make it. I tried different ways without any success.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# example path names after daytime this file incudes aroud 12k files 
# path = '/Users/kacper/data_lic/2022-06-10_16-28-28/content_file'
# path = '/Users/kacper/data_lic/2022-09-22_14-20-08/content_file'


for filename in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        out = open('file_paths.txt', 'a') # result file
        out.write(f + '\n')
        out.close()
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do and how your code doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: Maybe `glob.glob('/Users/kacper/data_lic/*/content_file')`?

Comment: @Barmar thx a lot for a tip. Just rebuilded code and i got expected result in 6 lines of code

Comment: `import glob`
`path = glob.glob('/Users/kacper/data_lic/*/*')`

`with open('dirs_names.txt', 'w') as fp:`
 `for item in path:`
        `fp.write('%s\n' % item)`

Comment: You can post that as an Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob

path = glob.glob('/Users/kacper/data_lic/*/*') with open('dirs_names.txt', 'w') as 
   fp: for item in path: 
      fp.write('%s\n' % item)
```